# Windows Mobile 6.0 Development with Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net

I have to develop a VB.Net application for a handheld scanner device. Todays scanners have a Windows CE or Windows Mobile 6.x installed.

1) According to Microsoft information it should be possible to develop such application using VS2013 (VB.Net) and the scanner should run Windows Mobile 8.0.
Anybody who has experience with that ?

2) Wich version of Visual Studio should be used for scanner devices running Windows CE or Windows Mobile 6.x ?

Thanks in advance, Dirk